# CSS3 overflow-y:scroll issue when height 100% in IE 11

Tags: html, css

Here is the code to reproduce this problem which happens in IE 11 but not chrome where it works well.
The issue is the reddiv does not overflow scroll when height is 100% but works for a fixed height like it does in chrome (try it in chrome and you will see). This code is part of my app that i dug out of it.
The reddiv should be 100% height of the reciperightcolumn.
I want height to be dynamic so no fixed height answers plz.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Contact - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="pagetable">
        <tr>
            <td id="pagecolumn1">

            </td>
            <td id="pagecolumn2">
    <div id="divrecipepad" style="background-color:yellow;">

    <table id="recipetable">
    <tr>
        <td id="recipeleftcolumn">
            <div id="divrecipelist"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="reciperightcolumn">
            <div style="height:100%;overflow-y:scroll">
                  Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                  Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                Blah Blah Blah blah<br />
                test<br />
                test<br />
                test<br />
                test<br />
                test<br />
                test<br />
                          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>

            </td>
            <td id="pagecolumn3">
                <div id="picframe">

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>


</body>
```

```
html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height:100%;
}

body {
/*background: url("PageImages/retina_wood.png"),repeat;*/ 
font-size: .85em;
font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}


#pagetable {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#pagecolumn1 {
width:20%;
/*background-color:green;*/
}

#pagecolumn2 {
width:60%;
/*background-color:blue;*/
}

#pagecolumn3 {
width:20%;
/*background-color:green;*/
}

#divrecipepad {
width:90%;
height:90%;
margin:auto;
background-color:white;
box-shadow:10px 10px 20px black;
border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
padding-bottom:7px;
}
#recipetable {
width:98%;
height:82%;
margin:auto;
background-color:green;

}

#recipeleftcolumn {
width:30%;
/*background-color:aqua;*/
vertical-align:top;
}

#reciperightcolumn {
width:70%;
background-color:lightcoral;
vertical-align:top;
}

#divrecipelist {
width:100%;
height:100%;
overflow-y:auto;
}

#tablerecipelist td {
padding:1px;
}

#divrecipelist a {
color:green;
margin-left:5px;
}

#divrecipe {
width:96%;
height:100%;
padding-left:15px;
margin:auto;
overflow-y:scroll;
font-size: .8em;
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: I've been working with a similar layout. I know you said no fixed height answers, but it's the only thing that's worked for me. Instead of height: 100% (which doesn't work well with nested containers) I was able to achieve this with a fixed (or absolute) position having top: 0 and bottom: 0. Using height of 100% isn't quite as predictable in all cases (to me).

Comment: This is what I tried, but didn't work.    style="position:relative;top:0;bottom:0;overflow-y:scroll"

Comment: This style was for the reddiv.

Comment: use position absolute or fixed, jquery is an option?

Comment: Yes jquery is ok. Can you tell me how?